# Azure shows directory content

Tags: azure

After I published my azure cloud service to azure, I got as result the following:

[image: The result]

Do you know what the problem is? I am using asp.net 4.0 mvc razor. I think, it doesn't load the webconfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the solution to take a Azure Website and not a Web Role and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a Default.aspx.  You can either add a Default.aspx, or you can modify the web.config's <[defaultDocument](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/22/how-to-add-a-default-document-with-iis7-web-config.aspx)> property.

Comment: So, what do I need to put in the defaultDocument tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can have following configuration in web.Config -

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="HtmlPage1.html" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And in RoutesConfig.cs -

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("");
```

Having IgnoreRoute() will make ASP.Net to fetch the default document specified in the web.config, instead of Routes engine to process route. And defaultDocument tag will make that file to be served for default URL "/".